# Qt QList C3892: cannot assign to a variable that is const

Tags: c++, qt, constants, const-correctness, qlist

I have const correctness issue with QList.

I have a method `getValue` whose signature i cannot change returning const double and here

```
double vs = MinInput->getValue(0, 0);
```

vs is const.

I would like to build QList with results from this method and i get error C3892.

Since my list is a QList, cannot add const double (?)

Code is like that

```
    QList<double> minmax;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2*(3+othercutoffs_var_len) ; i++  )
        minmax.append( 0.0 );


    QSP< const VarInterface<double> > MinInput = ctx.getInputVar<double>(ctx.input(Id::fromString(QL1s("Min")))[0] );
    const double vs = MinInput->getValue(0, 0);
    minmax.at(0) = vs;
```

and this very last line of code is getting me into trouble. (other errors when filling the list with other such const doubles)

signature for getValue is like that

```
const TYPE & VarData<TYPE>::getValue( uint r, uint c ) const
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the correct code would be:

```
minmax[0] = vs;
```

Update:

`QList::at` returns `const` reference, which cannot be modified.

Comment: why is it not doing it with at() ?

Comment: Because `QList::at` returns `const` reference, which cannot be modified. Signature: `const T & QList::at ( int i ) const`

Comment: QList uses 0-based indexes, just like C++ arrays. To access the item at a particular index position, you can use operator[](). On non-const lists, operator[]() returns a reference to the item and can be used on the left side of an assignment:

Answer (score 2):

`QList::at(int i)` is a getter function. It returns a `const` reference, and you cannot assign anything to it.

Use `QList::operator[](int i)` or `QList::replace(int i, const & T value)` to set the value at position `i`.